# Not able to see the logs in Custom Location in Kubernetes

Tags: docker, go, kubernetes, go-zap

I am using zap as the logger. I am storing the log in the custom location: /var/tmp/audit.log

Unfortunately, when I try to look at the logs in Kubernetes I am not able to find those logs. Can anyone suggest what I am missing? Do I have to volume mount the logs? I can find the logs if I do ssh into the Kubernetes pods but I can't find it when I do kubectl logs pod name

```
import (
    "go.uber.org/zap"
    "go.uber.org/zap/zapcore"
    "gopkg.in/natefinch/lumberjack.v2"
    "io"
)

var (
    Logger       *zap.Logger
    AuditLogging *zap.Logger
)

type WriteSyncer struct {
    io.Writer
}

func (ws WriteSyncer) Sync() error {
    return nil
}

func InitLogging(mode string) {
    var cfg zap.Config
    var logName = "/var/tmp/abc.log"
    var slogName = "/var/tmp/audit.log"

    if mode == "production" {
        cfg = zap.NewProductionConfig()
        cfg.DisableCaller = true
    } else {
        cfg = zap.NewDevelopmentConfig()
        cfg.EncoderConfig.LevelKey = "level"
        cfg.EncoderConfig.NameKey = "name"
        cfg.EncoderConfig.MessageKey = "msg"
        cfg.EncoderConfig.CallerKey = "caller"
        cfg.EncoderConfig.StacktraceKey = "stacktrace"
    }

    cfg.Encoding = "json"
    cfg.EncoderConfig.TimeKey = "timestamp"
    cfg.EncoderConfig.EncodeTime = zapcore.ISO8601TimeEncoder
    cfg.OutputPaths = []string{logName}
    sw := getWriteSyncer(logName)
    swSugar := getWriteSyncer(slogName)

    l, err := cfg.Build(SetOutput(sw, cfg))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer l.Sync()

    ls, err := cfg.Build(SetOutput(swSugar, cfg))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer ls.Sync()

    Logger = l
    AuditLogging = ls
}

// SetOutput replaces existing Core with new, that writes to passed WriteSyncer.
func SetOutput(ws zapcore.WriteSyncer, conf zap.Config) zap.Option {
    var enc zapcore.Encoder
    switch conf.Encoding {
    case "json":
        enc = zapcore.NewJSONEncoder(conf.EncoderConfig)
    case "console":
        enc = zapcore.NewConsoleEncoder(conf.EncoderConfig)
    default:
        panic("unknown encoding")
    }

    return zap.WrapCore(func(core zapcore.Core) zapcore.Core {
        return zapcore.NewCore(enc, ws, conf.Level)
    })
}

func getWriteSyncer(logName string) zapcore.WriteSyncer {
    var ioWriter = &lumberjack.Logger{
        Filename:   logName,
        MaxSize:    10, // MB
        MaxBackups: 3,  // number of backups
        MaxAge:     28, //days
        LocalTime:  true,
        Compress:   false, // disabled by default
    }
    var sw = WriteSyncer{
        ioWriter,
    }
    return sw
}
```

Here is how my yaml looks like

```
 apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert -f docker-compose.yml
    kompose.version: 1.22.0 (955b78124)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: service
  name: service
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      io.kompose.service: service
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        kompose.cmd: kompose convert -f docker-compose.yml
        kompose.version: 1.22.0 (955b78124)
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: service
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: services
          imagePullPolicy: Never
          name: service
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5001
            - containerPort: 5002
          resources: {}
          volumeMounts:
           - name: varlog
             mountPath: /var/tmp
      restartPolicy: Always  
      
      volumes:
      - name: varlog
        hostPath:
        path: /var/tmp
 status: {}



apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert -f docker-compose.yml
    kompose.version: 1.22.0 (955b78124)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: service
  name: service
spec:
  ports:
    - name: "5001"
      port: 5001
      targetPort: 5001
    - name: "5002"
      port: 5002
      targetPort: 5002
  selector:
    io.kompose.service: service
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

Comment: Consider to log to standard out and standard error. This is the common way to work with kubernetes clusters. Find here the documentation of the Logging Architecture of kubernetes https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/

Comment: @silverfighter: I have a specific kind of log. I don't want to log to standard out and standard error